# Regex to check odd number of occurance in string

Tags: java, regex

I want to make java regex to remove string "4040" before and after string, considering below scenarios.

**scenario : 1**

If whole string having even pair of 4040 then it will remove each pair and output will be empty string.

example :

- 4040404040404040 --> ""
- 40404040 --> ""

**scenario : 2**

In other case there can be some data in-between pairs of 4040 then it should return that string after removing 4040 from both size. No of pair both side can be any (also can be 0).

example:-

- 4040StackOverFlow4040 --> StackOverFlow
- 4040StackOverFlow40404040 --> StackOverFlow
- StackOverFlow4040 --> StackOverFlow
- 40404040StackOverFlow --> StackOverFlow

**scenario : 3**

If I having odd no of pairs for 4040 the it should return "4040". because middle one is actual data.

example:-

- 404040404040 --> 4040
- 40404040404040404040 --> 4040

Need one regex which can include all scenarios.

I tried by matching string using `^(4040)*|(4040)*$` and replace it with empty string. But it is not working for third scenario. Any way to detect odd number of pairs of 4040.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Ditto, but adding that regex doesn't "do" anything to the input string. It only matches parts/all of it. To "do" something, you need app code... please show some of that too. See [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Comment: Try to replace [`^(4040)(?:40404040)*$|^(?:4040)+|(?:4040)+$` with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/yVnqJU/1) This will 1.) If all string is composed from an uneven amount of `4040` replace the full string with the first occurance 2.) OR trim `4040` either from *start* or *end* of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regex? Just make life easy for yourself:

(pseudo code)

```
var string = ...
while (string.startsWith("4040") && string.endsWith("4040")) {
  string = string.substring(4, string.length - 4)
}
return string
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^((?:4040)+)(.*?)\\1$", "$2");
```

This works by requiring the same input front and back by way of the back reference `\1` to the front. The middle is captured as group `2`, which is used to replace the entire string, effectively "extracting" it.

Comment: `replaceFirst` could also be used to make it more efficient, since there is never going to be more than 1 match.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I disagree. Because this regex matches the entire input (it ends with `$`), it immediately halts. I strongly doubt you could measure the difference. The choice of method is based on style: Choose the one that makes for clearer code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vertical bar to [alternate](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) between different scenarios:

```
^(4040)(?:40404040)*$|^(?:4040)+|(?:4040)+$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yVnqJU/1) (replace to `$1`, [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) of the *first group*)

1. `^(4040)(?:40404040)*$` If all string is composed from an uneven amount of `4040`
    this will *capture* the first occurance and subsitute the string to the captured value.
2. `|^(?:4040)+` OR match [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) occurances [at the start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
3. `|(?:4040)+$` OR match one or more at the end of the string

For repetition of the substrings [`(?:` non capturing groups `)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) are used.